# Cronjob to check when Oracle Materialized View was last updated?

Tags: oracle, materialized-view

I have two database users in my Oracle DB and want to create MV's in User B which get their data from User A through a database link.

I plan to autorefresh the MV's every night but want to make sure the MV's are always up to date if something doesn't work with the autorefresh.

I found two kind of meta-data about the MV's: "LAST_REFRESH_TYPE" and "LAST_REFRESH_DATE".

Does the "LAST_REFRESH_DATE" always contain the date when my data was successfully refreshed the last time or just the date when a refresh was started (and perhaps failed)?

Comment: Is that column from DBA_MVIEWS?  I would think that it would be for a _successful_ refresh. Aside from that, it sounds like your two users are in the same database ("I have two database users in my Oracle DB").  If that is the case, there is no need to use a db_link ("which get their data from User A through a database link.").  Why do this with a cron job?  Why not a database job?